# JS split(", ") works in Browser console but not in Node

Tags: javascript, browser

I'm using Firefox, and tried this with node v14 and v17.
I'm trying to parse a string into a date:

```
const extractThreadDate = (page: string): Date => {
      const $ = cheerio.load(page)
      const posthead = $("div .posthead")
      const postdate = $(".postdate", posthead)
      // format: 25/01/2010, 12:37
      const textDate = postdate.first().text().trim()
      console.log("1", textDate)
      const [dayDate, hourDate] = textDate.split(", ")
      console.log("2", [dayDate, hourDate])
      const [day, month, year] = dayDate.split("/").map(s => Number(s))
      console.log("3", [day, month, year])
      const [hour, minute] = hourDate.split(":").map(s => Number(s))
      console.log("4", [hour, minute])
      const date = new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute)
      return date
}
```

However the logs show the following:

```
1 25/01/2010, 12:37
2 [ '25/01/2010, 12:37', undefined ]
3 [ 25, 1, NaN ]
```

Any hints?

Comment: `const [day, month, year, hour, minute] = textDate.match(/\d+/g).map(Number);`

Answer (score 2):

You can regex all whitespace using `/\s/g` in JavaScript, so to match this, you could do `.split(/,\s/g)` rather than targeting arbitrary/specific whitespace characters.

Answer (score 0):

So, I did a sanity check and noticed that `"25/01/2010, 12:37".split(", ")` works correctly by itself. Weirded out, I put a `fs.writeFileSync("hehehehe", textDate)`. Turns out there was a `\u00a0` character instead of a space. Amazing. Who thought it'd be a good idea to have another whitespace? Whatever, that was it, `split(",\u00a0")` works fine.

The reason it worked is that when you copy it to the clipboard, it apparently gets converted into a regular whitespace.

Comment: *'Who thought it'd be a good idea to have another whitespace'* really? There are 25 Unicode whitespace characters... see: [Whitespace character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character)

Comment: `"\u00a0"` is the same character as `&nbsp;` in html